# Como puedo obtener la MAC address del usuario por medio de nodejs?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, api, rest, npm

he tratado de halar la MAC en distintos dispositivos pero solo puedo jalar el del servidor, cuando subo mi api, he tratato de varias maneras:

```
getMacAd: async function(req, res) {

    var mac_address = address.mac(function(err, addr) { return addr });

    network.get_gateway_ip(function(err, dns) {
        if (!err) {
            arp.getMAC(String(dns), function(err, mac) {
                if (!err) {
                    res.status(200).send({ MAC: mac, DNS: dns });
                }
            });
        } else {
            res.status(200).send({ MAC: 'No MAC', DNS: dns });
        }

    });

},
```

esta fue la ultima que probe y me jala la MAC de mi router cuando estoy haciendo prueba desde mi pc en

```
http://localhost:3700
```

pero cuando lo subo a heroku no me sale nada, me tira un error vacio, cuando uso este:

```
var mac_address = address.mac(function(err, addr) { return addr });
```

me tira la MAC de mi eth0 pero cuando la subo a heroku me tira la mac addres del servidor, no de mi pc nuevamente o de otro dispositivo, si uso este siguiente:

```
network.get_active_interface(function(err, obj) {

})
```

este es del npm network igual que el primero, pensaba que me funcionaria ya que me tira la network activa con internet y me devuelve la MAC, en mi caso es Wi-Fi y me devuelve la MAC de mi dispositivo conectado a internet, pero cuando la subo a heroku sale vacía, alguien tiene una idea?

quiero crear una plataforma que solo se conecte una persona por MAC pero necesito obtener la MAC de cada computador con su respectivo usuario.

Answer (score 0):

En tu casa, puedes usar ARP para saber a qué MAC le "prestaron" cierta IP interna. Esto básicamente porque en la red interna hay un mapa sin el cual el router (casero, nivel 2) no sabría cómo enrutar los paquetes. Si entras a la configuración de éste verás que tiene una lista de IPs y MAC en la sección DHCP.

Fuera de tu casa, el router siguiente es de nivel 3 y enruta los paquetes usando la IP. Ya no hay tal cosa como MAC <--> IP. Tu equipo no manda eso en un request HTTP (por tanto TCP) a herou